# Catch mousve hover on text and highlight related value

Tags: javascript, text, hover, highlight

[image]

If you look at the attached image, in the second table, when the cursor moves to the cell contains `4`, all correspond text in the first table will get highlighted. I managed to acheive this using `hover` function :

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function HightLightTable1() {

    // 0 
    $(".t1_h_x0").hover(
function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    $(".t1_t_x0").css("background-color", "yellow");
}, function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    $(".t1_t_x0").css("background-color", "white");
}
);

    // 1 
    $(".t1_h_x1").hover(
function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    $(".t1_t_x1").css("background-color", "yellow");
}, function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    $(".t1_t_x1").css("background-color", "white");
}
);
// and keep adding code here if there are more tables 
}
```

This will lead to alot of html code also, for example, the first table :

[image]

Now I'm re-designing the site, and came to wonder is there any more efficient way to achieve this?

Link to my [site](http://iketqua.net) if you want to take a look

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your code by giving all the cells to be hovered the same class name and then use the cells text to build a query to adress the right spans like this:

```
$(".hovercell").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
        $(".t1_t_x"+$(this).text()).css("background-color", "yellow");
    }, function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
        $(".t1_t_x"+$(this).text()).css("background-color", "white");
    }
);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/markai/o3arj251/